# PostgreSQL 9.5 - func doesn't enter the loop

Tags: postgresql, function, loops, plpgsql

I created a function that doesn't work well. It doesn't enter the loop and I don't understand why.

My func:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Control_Reports_Pg.control_reports_fn (P_Report_Type smallint, P_Log_File_Name text,C_Path text) RETURNS bigint AS $body$
   DECLARE

   V_Return smallint;
   V_Function_Return smallint:=1;
   C_Daily_Reports varchar(400);

    C_Function_Name    varchar(200) := 'Control_Reports_Fn';
    Rec_Daily_Reports CONTROL_REPORTS%ROWTYPE;

  BEGIN

    C_Daily_Reports := 'SELECT REPORT_ORDER,PROCEDURE_NAME,DIRECTORY_NAME,FILE_NAME,TITLE FROM CONTROL_REPORTS WHERE RUN_FLAG=1::bigint AND REPORT_TYPE=' || P_Report_Type || '::smallint ORDER BY REPORT_ORDER ';

    RAISE NOTICE 'sql to run over in loop : %',C_Daily_Reports;

    FOR Rec_Daily_Reports IN EXECUTE C_Daily_Reports
     LOOP
     RAISE NOTICE 'INSIDE LOOP OF CONTROL_REPORTS, Procedure_name : %, File_name : %, Directory_name : %',Rec_Daily_Reports.Directory_Name,Rec_Daily_Reports.File_Name, Rec_Daily_Reports.Title;
     END LOOP;
     ........

mydb=> \d control_reports;
       Table "mysc.control_reports"
 Column     |          Type          | Modifiers
 ----------------+------------------------+-----------
  report_order   | bigint                 |
  report_type    | smallint               |
  procedure_name | character varying(100) |
  directory_name | character varying(100) |
  file_name      | character varying(100) |
  title          | character varying(500) |
  run_flag       | bigint                 |
```

The errors I get when I run the func from psql:

```
mysc=>  select control_reports_pg.control_reports_fn(1::smallint , 
      'daily_log_control_file.txt'::text,'/PostgreSQL/comb_logs'::text);
  NOTICE:  sql to run over in loop : SELECT 
  REPORT_ORDER,PROCEDURE_NAME,DIRECTORY_NAME,FILE_NAME,TITLE FROM CONTROL_REPORTS 
  WHERE RUN_FLAG=1::bigint AND REPORT_TYPE=1::smallint ORDER BY REPORT_ORDER
   NOTICE:  FUNC : Control_Reports_Fn, SQLERRM: invalid input syntax for 
   integer: "Chrg_in_b"
```

When I run the select in psql I don't get any errors and I get a result. Chrg_in_b is the value of the column Procedure_name of the first row that I get back from the select query. (If I drop the `ORDER BY` I just get a different procedure_name but same error).

Comment: `REPORT_TYPE` column is of type INT, `P_Report_Type` parameter is of type BIGINT, and finally this parameter is converted to string in this place of the query: `AND REPORT_TYPE=' || P_Report_Type || ' ORD` because there are apostophes around it.

Comment: I made the correction you specified (watch main comment) but it still doesnt help. Same error.

Comment: Something werid, when I use select * and not the specific columns it works.. Why is that ?

Comment: The `Rec_Daily_Reports` variable is of type `CONTROL_REPORTS%ROWTYPE` so your SQL should provide all fields (or possibly all `NOT NULL` fields, but I'd go with all) in the CONTROL_REPORTS table.

Comment: So if I want only some firelds how do i need to configure Rec_Daily_Reports ?

Comment: @Mariel Just declare it as `record`: `Rec_Daily_Reports record;`

Comment: PS: Error was caused by trying to store `PROCEDURE_NAME` value (second field in the query) to the `report_type` field of the `Rec_Daily_Reports` variable (second field in the table).